# Android Smart Location Library is always connected to gps after application closed

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps

I'm developing an application which gets the user location at start. I am using [Smart Location Library](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib) to fetch the location and reverse geocode. But the main problem is that GPS is connected showing in notification even after application closed. I checked the stack trace but did not found any leaked window exception there.
I'm using this code to fetch my location..

```
private void getMyLocation(){
    final long mLocTrackingInterval = 1000000 * 5; // 5 sec
    float trackingDistance = 1000 * 10;
    LocationAccuracy trackingAccuracy = LocationAccuracy.HIGH;
    LocationParams.Builder builder = new LocationParams.Builder()
                .setAccuracy(trackingAccuracy)
                .setDistance(trackingDistance)
                .setInterval(mLocTrackingInterval);
    SmartLocation.with(mContext)
                .location(provider)
                // .continuous()
                .oneFix()
                .config(builder.build())
                .start(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationUpdated(Location location) {
    SmartLocation.with(mContext).geocoding()
            .reverse(location,new OnReverseGeocodingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAddressResolved(Location location, List<Address> results) {
                    if (results.size() > 0) {
                        mAddressList=results;
                        mLocation=location;
                        tvLocation.setText( results.get(0).getAddressLine(0)+"\n"+results.get(0).getAddressLine(1));
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

And `onStop()` method of the Main actvity..

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SmartLocation.with(mContext).location(provider).stop();
    SmartLocation.with(mContext).geocoding().stop();
}
```

**Edit**

I'm using this povider. I've tried other providers too. But still the same result.

```
private LocationGooglePlayServicesWithFallbackProvider provider=new LocationGooglePlayServicesWithFallbackProvider(mContext);
```

I've tried a lot but am not able to figure out what is the actual problem. Any help would be Appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What `provider` are you using?

Comment: @azizbekian i'm using `LocationGooglePlayServicesWithFallbackProvider`  also tried other provider too

Comment: Use SmartLocation.with(context).location().stop(); to stop location listening.

Comment: @VivekSinha I've added this code on `onStop()` method of Activty already.

Comment: Have you tested the .stop() methods? You can do so by calling the .stop() methods manually, that is trigged by a button, so you know those calls work.

Comment: @Abhishek Singh Do you really wanted to use https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib ? Location services can be customized within Activity/Fragment/Service even.... Where more flexibility comes with respect to our app functionality

Comment: @Flummox i have'nt tried .. let me try that..

Comment: @Stallion its makes easy to every work like forword/reverse geocoding, geofencing,Activity recognition.. I need to use these feature and this library easily providing these features

Comment: 1000000 * 5; // 5 sec );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an App to stay responsive a lot of things are done Async. This is a good thing. It looks like the Library you use works that way. See the [Sample of MainActivity.java](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/io/nlopez/smartlocation/sample/MainActivity.java). `onActivityResult()` is the one you are looking for.

So, when does it come back with data? We just don't know for sure...

How do you stop it then? Well, that is an other part of Android. Please see this [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html). You will notice that while `onStop()` is *usually* called, it is not the first thing when the user does other stuff. If you wait for `onStop()` to be called, you don't know when that is. *If a user moves away from an App and manually deletes it from memory, only onPause() is called for sure, the rest in my experience is a bit of hit and miss.*

So if you want to kill the GPS when the user moves away (but your App is still in the memory, ready to receive notices) you do that in `onPause()`. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (SmartLocation == still_running) { // pseudo code
        SmartLocation.with(mContext).location(provider).stop();
        SmartLocation.with(mContext).geocoding().stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, basically, you claim that `onStop()` is **not** guaranteed to be called, whereas `onPause()` is, which is not true. `onStop()` will be called even in the case when `user moves away from an App and manually deletes it from memory`.

Comment: That is indeed my experience. I know the Docs say it is called every time. But it created an error in an App of mine due to being called, if at all, at and other time then expected.

Comment: Can you post a simple project demonstrating that behaviour? I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: For now, no. As I don't think it will help with the Original question. (as that would be a different question, and I have it working the way I want) Do you have an (other) idea where it might go wrong with this Question?

Comment: If I had a precise answer, which I could clarify, I would post it. As long as I do not have one, I see how others do that.

Comment: I don't know why `onStop()` not called everytime. It should be called according to Developer Docs

Comment: @Abhishek Singh, what made it work for you? Moving to the onPause()?

Comment: yes @Flummox. `onActivityResult` has no use cause its for `LocationGooglePlayServicesProvider` and i'm using `LocationGooglePlayServicesWithFallbackProvider`